# scala regular expression for string patterns

Tags: regex, scala

```
val fields = Set("abc", "abcd", "abc per", "uio abcd", "yrabc", "entry", "peer")

def matchFields(param: String): Set[String] = ????
```

if I am providing input `"abc"` to `matchFields` method above; I am expecting the response as `Set("abc", "abcd", "abc per", "uio abcd", "yrabc")`.

Can I know the implementation suggestions in scala with the help of regular expressions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regular expressions here:

```
def matchFields(param: String): Set[String] = fields.filter(_.contains(param))

scala> matchFields("abc")
res0: Set[String] = Set(uio abcd, abc, abc per, yrabc, abcd)
```

`contains` checks that one string is a substring of another, `filter` filters out elements, that not match given predicate.

If you really really want regexps:

```
import scala.util.matching._

scala> def matchFields(R: Regex): Set[String] = fields.collect{case str@R() => str}
matchFields: (R: scala.util.matching.Regex)Set[String]

scala> matchFields(".*abc.*".r)
res5: Set[String] = Set(uio abcd, abc, abc per, yrabc, abcd)
```

Or:

```
scala> def matchFields(R: Regex): Set[String] = fields.flatMap(R.findFirstIn)
matchFields: (R: scala.util.matching.Regex)Set[String]

scala> matchFields(".*abc.*".r)
res7: Set[String] = Set(uio abcd, abc, abc per, yrabc, abcd)
```

`.*` means 0 or more of any symbol. `.r` creates `Regex` from `String`